# Implement wordpress Password Reset link in html mail?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to replace the WP core password reset mail with an Html mail. Works in general very well, the mail gets formatted nicely and is sent properly. However, implementing the dynamic reset link doesn't work (also username but that's not even the most important thing)

I used the following code in my template's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','prefix_set_content_type' );
function prefix_set_content_type() {
        return "text/html";
}

add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'replace_retrieve_password_message', 10, 2 );
function replace_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {

        $message = '<html...>a lot of html content (basically formatted mail)</html>'
```

with this, it gives me a critical error due to expecting 4 arguments in the function and only receiving 2 (That's what the error report mail said). When I leave out the $user_data and $key the error disappears but still I don't know how to implement the dynamic link...

When I try to include this in the Html, it will only send half of the link (probably due to something with '""'):
`

```
' . network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' ) . '
```

Anyone some ideas on how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: The 4th parameter of `add_filter` says how many parameters the callback function expects.

Answer (score 0):

Put 4 at the end of this line, not 2.

```php
add_filter('retrieve_password_message', 'replace_retrieve_password_message',10,4);
```

You have to tell [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) and [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) how many parameters the hook function takes.

Comment: omg so stupid haha thanks. sometimes it's the smallest of things...